# A4 Landscape Orientation Printing

Tags: html, css, printing, media-queries

I have screens in Zeplin that I need to make with HTML, CSS so they are ready to print on A4 (Landscape orientation). Their dimension is 842px x 595px which seems like good dimension for the A4 format but when I tried to print it, it is not covering full screen.

This is my css:

```
page {
background: white;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-bottom: 0.2cm;
}
page[size="A4"][layout="portrait"] {
box-sizing: border-box;
page-break-inside: avoid;
width: 842px;
height: 595px; 
display: flex; 
}
@media print{  
@page {
  size: A4 landscape;
}
}
```

Comment: Check weather you have added border sizes when printing the page

Comment: where should I add it? in @media print section?

Comment: Printing pixels? Use mm or cm units in your print CSS.